# Question about a complex sentence

Tags: complex-sentences

Is 'Three years after the attack, Betty Elliot was living among the Aucas.' a complex sentence or a simple sentence?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. In order for us to answer a question like this, you need to explain fully what you believe it is one or the other, for example, "My textbook defines a simple sentence as X and a complex sentence as Y. I think this sentence is simple because Z, but I am confused because my teacher also said W." Please [edit](http://english.stackexchange.com/posts/299841/edit) your post to include this background. Our sister site for [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) may also be of interest.

Answer (score 2):

As written, this is a **simple sentence** because it doesn't contain any dependent clauses.

[Examples of a complex sentence](http://examples.yourdictionary.com/complex-sentence-examples.html) are as follows.

> Because my coffee was too cold, I heated it in the microwave.
>   Though
>   he was very rich, he was still very unhappy.
>   She returned the computer
>   after she noticed it was damaged.
>   When the cost goes up, customers buy
>   less clothing.

[YourDictionary.Com]

Comment: Whoops, you're right. My mistake!

Comment: Consider it done.

Comment: Hi, John, Welcome to EL&U. Linking just a website is not encouraged in this community as your link can become invalid if the linked page changes. Please include essential parts of the link in your post and make sure that you take the [tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit our [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Rathony. The website link isn't actually relevant to my answer, it was just for examples of the other kind of sentence, but I'll keep that in mind in my future answers.

Comment: I've just edited your post for your guidance. (We always do it for a new user) Please take a look. You can see what was changed by clicking on **edited X mins ago** above my username. :-)